# PHP downloading instead of opening in browser - MacOS Sierra

Tags: php, apache, macos-sierra

I'm having issues related to loading php using Apache. I use a iMac running Sierra 10.12.6. Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (Unix). PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Feb 7 2017 (16:18:37). Loaded module: php7_module (shared). I have been making all changes using Terminal. So far I can access my localhost, getting the "It Works!" page. I can access my user directory, for html documents only.

When I load the php5 module localhost will not connect at all. Server localhost not found. When I comment the php5 load module out again and restart apache I can gain access html documents in both localhost and localhost/~. When php5 is not loaded it downloads the document instead of opening it. It will go to the downloads folder or open in a text editor like Dreamweaver automatically. I downloaded MAMP and can access the phpinfo page and localhost on port 8888 so I think that is Ok, although I'm having issues connecting MySQL. That's a separate issue. Right now I just want to access php in my localhost/~.

My user directory info is (using actual username)

```
<Directory "Users/username/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I followed tutorials making the recommended changes to the httpd.conf and other files and creating the index.html and php info documents in ~/Sites.

```
LoadModule userdir_mod
AddHandler php5-script php
display_errors = On
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf
```

I also changed the ServerName to localhost:80.
I also changed permissions on my WebServer/Documents folder to read & write for system, wheel and everyone.
I also made the following changes after reading through message boards on this site making changes to the Directory index.

I made other changes to the bash file (following the tutorial) and eventually reloaded the original httpd but I still can't access php. How do i access php5 in my user directory? Thanks.

Comment: Please format your question properly, as is nobody will bother to decrypt it...

Answer (score 0):

Either some modules are missing, or a misconfiguration in your httpd.conf file. The correct AddType for php is:

```
AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps
```

And make sure your module is loaded. Depending on the PHP version you are using, this is something like:

```
LoadModule php5_module        modules/mod_php56.so
```

Restart your Apache and clear your browser cache before testing your php pages. Or try to upgrade to PHP 7. Unlink the old PHP and add the new:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
brew unlink php56
brew install php71
```

Comment: I made the recommended changes and it still does not work. Other posts mention html permission issues in the public directory but I have checked that too.

Comment: Files are still downloaded? Did you clear your browser history?

Comment: Yes. Still doesn't work. I don't know what modules could be missing.

Comment: I upgraded php using the liip-ch curl installation, recommended in the tutorial. Also, I was having the problem before the upgrade. Perhaps installing with homebrew would have been a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out to be a permissions error.  Try creating a new folder and copy across all the files.